# Visual Studio C++ cannot open some headers I didn't deliberately include

Tags: c++, console-application, windows-10

today I wanted to start learning C++.
However I keep getting these errors:

> Cannot open source file "stdio.h"
>   Cannot open source file "tchar.h"
>   Cannot open source file "SDKDDKver.h"

However, I even get these in a default empty win32 console project.

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

OS: windows 10

My default code looks like this:

```
    // HelloWorld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"


    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

The errors are:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "stdio.h"   HelloWorld  c:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\stdafx.h    10  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "tchar.h"   HelloWorld  c:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\stdafx.h    11  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h"   HelloWorld  c:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\targetver.h 8   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "stdio.h"   HelloWorld  c:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\stdafx.h    10
```

In the OUTPUT window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

EDIT:

I believe I have C++ installed, cause first when I went to 
file > new > project > Visual C++ 
It would only show me "Install ... for C++", So I installed one of the first options (don't remember which one it was) and after installing it allowed me to create projects.

Comment: Looks like you have a bad install of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @drescherjm so i have to re install it?

Comment: C++ doesn't install by default. If you didn't do a custom install, you should modify (no need to uninstall and reinstall) and this time ask for C++. If you believe you chose C++ when installing, please edit your question to say so.

Comment: @KateGregory updated the post

Comment: That may have given you C++ project support, but will not necessarily have installed the Windows SDK. Note: if you want to learn C++, start by not doing any Windows-specific stuff. Drop that stdafx.h include, and set the project not to use precompiled headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `stdafx.h` contents. Headers can be included transitively. In particular, the three ehaders you quote are in the VC++ stdafx.h for new projects. You can simply remove them if you're programming C++.

(It says something about Microsoft's struggle to choose between C and C++ : They don't support C99, but they default to a C header instead of C++. Not even `<cstdio>`. )